# Messed up my characters head

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

When I subdivided it destroyed this gentleman's face. I am absolute beginner trying to run through tutorials but I cannot see what I did wrong, I have an older version of this character but would rather not go back since I did some good work on details like the ribs and chest and belly button as you can see in the photo. I am going to be rigging him up next and i don't want to make a pill mouth[image]

Comment: Try this: select the head object, go into edit-mode, select all the vertices (A), hit ctrl+N. If this doesn't work, try deleting doubles with all vertices selected.

Comment: Looks like you need to re-uv unwrap the bottom part of his face.

Comment: My man Bert saved the day! It was doubles that needed to be removed. I was dreading David's suggestion but the uvs are messed up anyway and i am just going to proceed with rigging now cause it's a learning process. Thanks all.